# Message via Oracle12c not being sent to DLQ Azure ServiceBus queue

Tags: azure, oracle12c, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am an oracle developer and I am working on a project where I use Oracle 12c (version 12.2.1.0.0).

I created a REST call to a queue on the Azure Service Bus, but every time I send the message via Oracle it drops into DLQ and stays there and does not forward to the main Queue.

Has anyone here gone through this: Call azure via REST in an Oracle environment and get your message on DLQ?

My actions was to create a Proxy Service and a pipeline calling my Business Service that is calling Azure Service

No code to display now

No error is displayed, just sending message to DLQ

Comment: When the message ends up in the Service Bus dead-letter, what's the delivery count on it? What's the `MaxDeliveryCount` on the queue? Also, when the message is dead-lettered, what's the reason (it should be in the customer properties/headers of the message).

Comment: good evening! Request this information from an azure person to answer about MaxDeliveryCount.

Another thing, I will inform the type of content and the authorization, is it because of this?

Update:

Got the answer, it's set to 10